# React Native Clipboard returns different than console log

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why is it that when I try to console log the Clipboard text, it comes out correctly, but when I try to return it in my component, its an object?

This is what it looks like when i try to return content

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getContent();
  }, []);


  const getContent = async e => {
    try {
      const content =  await Clipboard.getString();
      return content;
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;

      return errors;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Clipboard: {JSON.stringify(getContent())}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This comes out to be: `{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}` but when I change the `try` statement from

```
return content;
```

to

```
console.log(content);
```

i get the correct clipboard in the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example I believe what happens is the following:

1) When you print to console, it doesn't print until the has been fulfilled.

2) When you return the value of the Promise on the initial render, it returns the current value of the Promise `content`, but at that moment in time it has not yet been fulfilled (which is the stringified and not very descriptive `object`).

What you could do is to use the `useState` hook (see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html and https://gist.github.com/michalchudziak/f99d403abe90f11e8146c6f75416a0c8 for reference). This will allow you to render an initial value and then re-render once the value has been updated (when Promise has fulfilled or returned an error).

Please note that you should not render the return value of `getContent()`, but rather the `state` value, which should be set instead of `return content`.

See below for inspiration (not tested):

```
const App = () => {
  const [clipboardContent, setClipboardContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    getContent();
  }, []);


  const getContent = async e => {
    try {
      const content =  await Clipboard.getString();
      setClipboardContent(content);
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;
      setClipboardContent(errors); // Might want to deal with this differently
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Clipboard: { clipboardContent }</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```